# Pardonne à des maux ?

Tags: littérature

Dans *Andromaque*, III, I, Oreste dit :

> J'abuse cher, ami, de ton trop d'amitié ; / Mais pardonne à **des** maux
> dont toi seul as pitié ; / Excuse un malheureux qui perd tout ce qu'il
> aime, / Que tout le monde hait, et qui se hait lui-même.

Source : https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Racine_-_%C5%92uvres,_Didot,_1854.djvu/107

Pourquoi Racine a-t-il employé l'article indéfini ici (***à* *des* *maux***) ?

Comment: Parce que maux est au pluriel. Le pluriel des articles un ou une, c'est des. un mal, des maux.

Comment: Il aurait pu écrire "les maux"...

Comment: Ah, Racine ! Je me disais aussi, on ne reconnaissait plus le style de Céline... ;-)

Comment: @jiliagre Hahahahahahahaha

Comment: Je ne puis pardonner à **un** mal si fort.

Comment: *aux maux* aurait une syllabe de trop peu

Comment: Heureusement que Racine n'a pas  utilisé le singulier... : *pardonne à un mâle dont toi seul as pitié* ;-)

Comment: @jiliagre Pensez-vous que la question est superflue... ? Je me demandais en lisant ce passage si l'article indéfini (à des maux) ne créait plutôt une distance entre Oreste et Pylade.

Comment: Aux mots n'y faut ?

Comment: Non, la question est intéressante, Je ne perçois pas d'effet de distance avec *des* et trouve l'article indéfini approprié ici, les maux en question ne sont pas précisément définis. Les contraintes de l'alexandrin auraient aussi imposé une autre formulation, comme l'a écrit Peter Shor.

Comment: @jlliagre D'accord, merci pour votre avis !

Answer (score 1):

L'idée, en n'employant pas l'article défini, ce qui aurait donné « Mais pardonne aux maux dont toi seul a pitié », c'est de ne pas demander qu'un pardon soit accordé à tous les maux dont son interlocuteur a pitié parce que tous ces maux n'ont pas un impact dans la situation à laquelle réfère Oreste, et il n'est  pas approprié de le faire ; la restriction à la situation que le contexte définit étant quelque chose qu'il connait lui assure que sa demande est raisonnable ; il déclare que ce sont des maux de la sorte citée ; ces mots peuvent être soit non reconnus par son interlocuteur ou tout au contraire ils peuvent avoir été identifiés dans le contexte, et donc être connus des deux locuteurs,  mais cela ne résulte pas en la nécessité d'utiliser l'article défini ; la raison de ce fait c'est que le nom étant modifié, et faisant donc référence à un ensemble plus grand il est nécessaire de ne spécifier qu'une partie de cet ensemble, ce qui est fait au moyen de l'article indéfini.

On voit ce dernier principe dans le contexte suivant parce qu'il est plus familier.

- J'ai utilisé la technique A, la B, et la C aussi, tout comme vous l'avez fait ; ce sont des techniques parmi celles que vous connaissez. Si j'ai utilisé **des** techniques que vous connaissez, c'est que je comptait sur votre aide pour les dépannages.  (*Toutes les techniques qu'ils connaissent ne sont pas ce dont il/elle parle, il/elle ne fait référence qu'à A, B, et C, qui sont *des* techniques parmi celles qu'ils connaissent.*)